# Can the netstat command show what specific website a user is on?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ssh, ddos

I'm currently under an Apache DDoS attack and have 13 websites shared under one server. I can use the netstat command to see the # of connections per IP, but not what website they're actually on. I want to sign up with CloudFlare to stop the attack, but I don't know what specific site is being attacked. As one precaution, I've moved the 4 sites I think it could be to different IP's on my server.

I'm using this command to get the IP's and # of occurances:

```
netstat -n | grep ':80' | awk -F' ' '{print $5}' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

So, is there any way to show what specific website they're on?

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?

Comment: Have you researched the extensive archives here and on other SE machines for dealing with attacks on your server?

Answer (score 2):

No, `netstat` can't tell you that; it works on a level below Apache.

Apache will have to tell you which sites are being hit, generally through the logging mechanism.